# Send data from view to controller

Tags: java, jsp, vraptor

Hi i'm using a brazillian framework called Vraptor and now I have a object in my JSP

```
${solicitacao }
```

And now i want to send this object to the controller or back-end without need add inputs to put the information of the object.

Answer (score 0):

In general terms, there's no to send data from the view to the controller without using input fields, or embedding data in an url.  However, if you have the date already in a previous invocation of a controller, you could place the object in the session for later retrieval.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the session as: classe.campo
Note that the servlet runs on the server, and the "Controller" will be called only after being exeidos data in the browser screen, so you must use at least one object 'input type =' hidden '"